# Have calendar function grab only month and year

Tags: php, laravel, calendar

How would I have this function show items based solely on the year and months, and not the year month and day?

Date Format: YYYY-MM-DD I want it to only do YYYY-MM

**Code:**

```
  public function calendar($month = null, $year = null)
  {
  $now = Carbon::now();

  $month = $month ? $month : $now->month;
  $year = $year ? $year : $now->year;

  $date = new Carbon("{$year}-{$month}");

  //get the current month range
  $start = $date->startOfMonth()->toDateString();
  $end   = $date->endOfMonth()->toDateString();

  $items = $this->model->whereNotNull('poster')
  ->where('release_date', '>=', $start)
  ->where('release_date', '<=', $end)
  ->orderBy('release_date', 'asc')
  ->cacheTags('calendar')
  ->remember(-1)
  ->get()
  ->toArray();

  return array('year' => $date->year, 'month' => $date->month, 'items' => $items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, it's now only about the presentation. (Since you already use `startOfMonth()` and `endOfMonth()` to get your where statements right)

You can simply add an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) to your model to format the date:

```
public function getReleaseDate(){
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['release_date'])->format('Y-m');
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i was trying to see if that solution worked, but it didnt.

Comment: No problem. But I'm gonna need more information what didn't work if you want me to help you.